# Disable Magento RSS module - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, dependency

I have been disabling modules that we don't require and as anyone who has tried this knows some cannot simply be disabled because of dependencies. There are a number of modules we have absolutely no use for like Magento_Rss. I have read the Rss module can significantly slow down that backend so I thought - lets get rid of it. Does anyone know how to correctly remove a module that has dependencies?

The command

```
bin/magento module:disable Magento_Rss
```

Produces this in our setup

```
Unable to change status of modules because of the following constraints:
Cannot disable Magento_Rss because modules depend on it:
Magento_Store: Magento_Store->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Directory: Magento_Directory->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Theme: Magento_Theme->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Backend: Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Variable: Magento_Variable->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Eav: Magento_Eav->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_AdminNotification: Magento_AdminNotification->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Config: Magento_Config->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Indexer: Magento_Indexer->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Customer: Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Cms: Magento_Cms->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport: Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Search: Magento_Search->Magento_Reports->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Security: Magento_Security->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_User: Magento_User->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Authorization: Magento_Authorization->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Catalog: Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Rule: Magento_Rule->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Backup: Magento_Backup->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Quote: Magento_Quote->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Bundle: Magento_Bundle->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_GraphQl: Magento_GraphQl->Magento_Store->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_BundleImportExport: Magento_BundleImportExport->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Payment: Magento_Payment->Magento_Sales->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Integration: Magento_Integration->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_EavGraphQl: Magento_EavGraphQl->Magento_Eav->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_CatalogImportExport: Magento_CatalogImportExport->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_CatalogInventory: Magento_CatalogInventory->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl: Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Cron: Magento_Cron->Magento_Store->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Msrp: Magento_Msrp->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_CatalogRule: Magento_CatalogRule->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite: Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Widget: Magento_Widget->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Sales: Magento_Sales->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Checkout: Magento_Checkout->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Vault: Magento_Vault->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_CmsGraphQl: Magento_CmsGraphQl->Magento_Cms->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_CmsUrlRewrite: Magento_CmsUrlRewrite->Magento_Store->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_CmsUrlRewriteGraphQl: Magento_CmsUrlRewriteGraphQl->Magento_Store->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_ConfigurableImportExport: Magento_ConfigurableImportExport->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_ConfigurableProduct: Magento_ConfigurableProduct->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_StoreGraphQl: Magento_StoreGraphQl->Magento_Store->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_ConfigurableProductSales: Magento_ConfigurableProductSales->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Contact: Magento_Contact->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Cookie: Magento_Cookie->Magento_Store->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Email: Magento_Email->Magento_Theme->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_CurrencySymbol: Magento_CurrencySymbol->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Paypal: Magento_Paypal->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Analytics: Magento_Analytics->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_CustomerGraphQl: Magento_CustomerGraphQl->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_CustomerImportExport: Magento_CustomerImportExport->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Deploy: Magento_Deploy->Magento_Store->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Developer: Magento_Developer->Magento_Store->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Downloadable: Magento_Downloadable->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_CatalogGraphQl: Magento_CatalogGraphQl->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_ImportExport: Magento_ImportExport->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_BundleGraphQl: Magento_BundleGraphQl->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_CatalogSearch: Magento_CatalogSearch->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Newsletter: Magento_Newsletter->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_EncryptionKey: Magento_EncryptionKey->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_GiftMessage: Magento_GiftMessage->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_GoogleAdwords: Magento_GoogleAdwords->Magento_Sales->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_GoogleAnalytics: Magento_GoogleAnalytics->Magento_Sales->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Ui: Magento_Ui->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_ConfigurableProductGraphQl: Magento_ConfigurableProductGraphQl->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_GroupedImportExport: Magento_GroupedImportExport->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_GroupedProduct: Magento_GroupedProduct->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_GroupedProductGraphQl: Magento_GroupedProductGraphQl->Magento_GroupedProduct->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_DownloadableImportExport: Magento_DownloadableImportExport->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_CatalogWidget: Magento_CatalogWidget->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InstantPurchase: Magento_InstantPurchase->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_CatalogAnalytics: Magento_CatalogAnalytics->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InventoryAdminUi: Magento_InventoryAdminUi->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InventoryBundleProduct: Magento_InventoryBundleProduct->Magento_Bundle->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InventoryCatalog: Magento_InventoryCatalog->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InventorySales: Magento_InventorySales->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi: Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch: Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch->Magento_Store->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct: Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi: Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer: Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InventoryConfiguration: Magento_InventoryConfiguration->Magento_CatalogInventory->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct: Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct->Magento_GroupedProduct->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi: Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer: Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InventoryImportExport: Magento_InventoryImportExport->Magento_Store->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InventoryIndexer: Magento_InventoryIndexer->Magento_InventorySales->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification: Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi: Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InventoryProductAlert: Magento_InventoryProductAlert->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InventoryCache: Magento_InventoryCache->Magento_InventoryIndexer->Magento_InventorySales->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi: Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InventorySalesApi: Magento_InventorySalesApi->Magento_Sales->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi: Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi->Magento_CatalogInventory->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InventoryShipping: Magento_InventoryShipping->Magento_Sales->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Shipping: Magento_Shipping->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi: Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi->Magento_InventorySalesApi->Magento_Sales->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_MediaStorage: Magento_MediaStorage->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable: Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_MysqlMq: Magento_MysqlMq->Magento_Store->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_ProductAlert: Magento_ProductAlert->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_OfflinePayments: Magento_OfflinePayments->Magento_Checkout->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_SalesRule: Magento_SalesRule->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_PageCache: Magento_PageCache->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Persistent: Magento_Persistent->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Reports: Magento_Reports->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_ProductVideo: Magento_ProductVideo->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Captcha: Magento_Captcha->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_QuoteAnalytics: Magento_QuoteAnalytics->Magento_Quote->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_QuoteGraphQl: Magento_QuoteGraphQl->Magento_Quote->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_ReleaseNotification: Magento_ReleaseNotification->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Review: Magento_Review->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_ReviewAnalytics: Magento_ReviewAnalytics->Magento_Review->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Robots: Magento_Robots->Magento_Store->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_AdvancedSearch: Magento_AdvancedSearch->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_SalesAnalytics: Magento_SalesAnalytics->Magento_Sales->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_SalesInventory: Magento_SalesInventory->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_OfflineShipping: Magento_OfflineShipping->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_UrlRewrite: Magento_UrlRewrite->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Elasticsearch: Magento_Elasticsearch->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_CustomerAnalytics: Magento_CustomerAnalytics->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Wishlist: Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi: Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi->Magento_Sales->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Sitemap: Magento_Sitemap->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_DownloadableGraphQl: Magento_DownloadableGraphQl->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Webapi: Magento_Webapi->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Tax: Magento_Tax->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Tinymce3: Magento_Tinymce3->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_Translation: Magento_Translation->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_GoogleOptimizer: Magento_GoogleOptimizer->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_UrlRewriteGraphQl: Magento_UrlRewriteGraphQl->Magento_Store->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_AsynchronousOperations: Magento_AsynchronousOperations->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_WebapiAsync: Magento_WebapiAsync->Magento_Webapi->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Magento_WebapiSecurity: Magento_WebapiSecurity->Magento_Webapi->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Sm_BackEnd: Sm_BackEnd->Magento_AdminNotification->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Sm_Bestshop: Sm_Bestshop->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Sm_FilterProducts: Sm_FilterProducts->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Sm_ListingTabs: Sm_ListingTabs->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
Sm_MegaMenu: Sm_MegaMenu->Magento_Wishlist->Magento_Rss
```

Another one is Magento_Wishlist. Why so many dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Yes, it is a Magento bug. I hope near feature release this dependency will be resolved.***

On a Magento meet, Director of Architecture at Magento Commerce [**Anton Kril**](https://twitter.com/antonkril?lang=en), mention that they are aware of  this bug and near feature, they  will correct it